# Date format in Angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I have simple date object made in JS and I don't know why AngularJS can't bind it to the input control(Probably the problem is the format of date) but please explain me it. The sample problem occurs when I return Json object which contains date.

View:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-app>
    <input type="date" ng-model="dateVal" />
        <hr/>   
    {{dateVal}}  </br>    
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.dateVal = new Date(2013, 06,07);   
}
```

Entire example is placed
[here - jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2BZV4/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input control doesn't appear to bind to a date object, but a string object.

Change your dateVal to a string like

```
$scope.dateVal = "2013-06-07";
```

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2BZV4/2/

Comment: I was just about to post this very answer. Here's [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html) for the date input type. Something to keep in mind (although I'm sure the OP is aware) - not all browsers support that input type (Firefox doesn't, for example.)

Comment: I didn't check specyfication for date input I thought it's something with format and angularjs. Eh. Thanks a lot for help.